# Oracle's EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with LIKE clauses in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a procedure that returns the name of a sequence based on the schema name and table name parameters.

The procedure would look into `all_sequences` and find the correct sequence based on the given schema and table names. It would do this through an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command and insert the sequence name into a variable.

All the sequences are named either `s_[table_name]`, `seq_[table_name]` or `[table_name]_seq`.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
    PROCEDURE proc_find_sequence(  
                            shema_name VARCHAR2,
                            table_name VARCHAR2,
                        ) 
  IS
    
    sequence_name1      VARCHAR2(30);    
    
  BEGIN
  
    
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'SELECT s.sequence_name FROM all_sequences s 
   WHERE 
    s.SEQUENCE_OWNER = UPPER('||shema_name||')
  AND
  (
    s.sequence_name LIKE UPPER(''''S_%'''||table_name||')
    OR 
    s.sequence_name LIKE UPPER(''''SEQ_%'''||table_name||')
    OR
    s.sequence_name LIKE UPPER('||table_name||'''%_SEQ'''')
    )'
     INTO sequence_name1;
   
   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sequence_name1); 

END;
```

The error I get is "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis", although I'm sure the problem lies with the way I'm implementing the LIKE clauses with the parameters between the brackets.

Any help or idea for how to solve the problem would be apreciated.

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need dynamic SQL. Simply use this:

```
SELECT s.sequence_name 
FROM all_sequences s 
INTO sequence_name1
WHERE 
    s.SEQUENCE_OWNER = UPPER(shema_name)
  AND
  (
    s.sequence_name = UPPER('S_'||table_name)
    OR 
    s.sequence_name = UPPER('SEQ_'||table_name)
    OR
    s.sequence_name = UPPER(table_name||'_SEQ')
  )
```

or just

```
s.sequence_name IN (
    UPPER('S_'||table_name), 
    UPPER('SEQ_'||table_name), 
    UPPER(table_name||'_SEQ'))
```

A regular expression should also work

```
REGEXP_LIKE(s.sequence_name, '^S(EQ)?_'||table_name||'$', 'i')
   or REGEXP_LIKE(s.sequence_name, '^'||table_name||'_SEQ$', 'i')
```

Comment: In addition to answer from @Wernfried Domscheit which is spot on , you don't need a procedure rather a function which return type is `varchar2` and also it could happen that you get two result for which you need to handle the error with `too_many_rows` and return some text like `More than one sequence found` or whatever is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in using PL/SQL, which I believe you don't need it ( as the answer provided by @Wemfried ), you could try this. Take in account

-You yourself say that the sequence can take only one of those names `s_[table_name]`, `seq_[table_name]` or `[table_name]_seq`.

-Therefore you can use a single like expression, as `S%TABLE_NAME%` which covers all the scenarios.

```
set serveroutput on echo on
declare
shema_name varchar2(40)  := 'SYS' ;
table_name  varchar2(128) := 'MY_TABLE' ;
begin
dbms_output.put_line ( 'SELECT s.sequence_name FROM all_sequences s  
      where
      s.SEQUENCE_OWNER = UPPER('''||shema_name||''')
      AND
       s.sequence_name like UPPER(''%'||table_name||'%'')
       ' );
end;
/
```

If I execute this:

```
SQL> create table my_table ( c1 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> create sequence s_my_table start with 1 increment by 1 ;

Sequence created.

SQL> set serveroutput on echo on
declare
shema_name varchar2(40)  := 'SYS' ;
table_name  varchar2(128) := 'MY_TABLE' ;
begin
dbms_output.put_line ( 'SELECT s.sequence_name FROM all_sequences s
      where
      s.SEQUENCE_OWNER = UPPER('''||shema_name||''')
      AND
       s.sequence_name like UPPER(''%'||table_name||'%'')
       ' );
end;
/
  SELECT s.sequence_name FROM all_sequences s
  where
  s.SEQUENCE_OWNER = UPPER('SYS')
  AND
   s.sequence_name like UPPER('%MY_TABLE%')


 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT s.sequence_name FROM all_sequences s
      where
      s.SEQUENCE_OWNER = UPPER('SYS')
      AND
       s.sequence_name like UPPER('%MY_TABLE%')
  ;

SEQUENCE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S_MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take, not on what was wrong with your code, but on how to find the issue yourself when dealing with this type of problem.

Instead of constructing the query as part of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement, you should assign it to a variable. Then for debugging purposes, display what you've constructed. Then you can actually execute it by referencing the variable:

```
    PROCEDURE proc_find_sequence(  
                            shema_name VARCHAR2,
                            table_name VARCHAR2,
                        ) 
  IS
    
    sequence_name1      VARCHAR2(30); 
    v_sql               varchar2(2048);   
    
  BEGIN
  
    
  v_sql := 
  'SELECT s.sequence_name FROM all_sequences s 
   WHERE 
    s.SEQUENCE_OWNER = UPPER('||shema_name||')
  AND
  (
    s.sequence_name LIKE UPPER(''''S_%'''||table_name||')
    OR 
    s.sequence_name LIKE UPPER(''''SEQ_%'''||table_name||')
    OR
    s.sequence_name LIKE UPPER('||table_name||'''%_SEQ'''')
    )'
     INTO sequence_name1;
   
  dbms_output_put_line(v_sql);
  execute immediate v_sql;
   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sequence_name1); 

END;
```